# pymongo, map_reduce result not same as mongo command line

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to mongodb but here is just my simple test.
Unfortunately, with same map/reduce function, I get different results from mongo command line and pymongo...
Pymongo is 3.0.3, mongodb is 3.0

Here is operations from command line:

```
map = function(){
... var date = new Date('2015-07-30');
... emit(date,this)
... }
function (){
var date = new Date('2015-07-30');
emit(date,this)
}

reduce = function(key, values){
... var sum = {'new':0,'act':0,'channel_new':{},'ver_new':{},'channel_ver_new':{}};
... values.forEach(function(doc){
... sum.new += doc.new;
... sum.act += doc.act;
... var category = {"channel_new":1,"ver_new":1,"channel_ver_new":1};
... for(var item in category)
... {
...   var t = Object.keys(doc[item]);
...   for(var i in t){
...    if(Object.keys(sum[item]).indexOf(t[i])!=-1){
...     sum[item][t[i]] += doc[item][t[i]];
...    }else{
...     sum[item][t[i]] = doc[item][t[i]];
...    }
...   }
... }
... });
... return sum;
... }
function (key, values){
var sum = {'new':0,'act':0,'channel_new':{},'ver_new':{},'channel_ver_new':{}};
values.forEach(function(doc){
sum.new += doc.new;
sum.act += doc.act;
var category = {"channel_new":1,"ver_new":1,"channel_ver_new":1};
for(var item in category)
{
  var t = Object.keys(doc[item]);
  for(var i in t){
   if(Object.keys(sum[item]).indexOf(t[i])!=-1){
    sum[item][t[i]] += doc[item][t[i]];
   }else{
    sum[item][t[i]] = doc[item][t[i]];
   }
  }
}
});
return sum;
}
db.daily.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:"wnitest"})
{
        "result" : "wnitest",
        "timeMillis" : 12,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 2,
                "emit" : 2,
                "reduce" : 1,
                "output" : 1
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Here is result:

```
db.daily.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55bef40cf6d9e26e37e3e37b"), "date" : ISODate("2015-07-06T00:00:00Z"), "new" : 1,
 "channel_ver_new" : { "111_0500_00*#*0\uff0E9\uff0E0" : 2 }, "ver_new" : { "0\uff0E9\uff0E0" : 2 },
 "channel_new" : { "111_0500_00" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55bef40cf6d9e26e37e3e37d"), "date" : ISODate("2015-07-07T00:00:00Z"), "new" : 2,
 "channel_ver_new" : { "111_0500_00*#*1\uff0E0\uff0E0" : 3 }, "ver_new" : { "1\uff0E0\uff0E0" : 3 },
 "channel_new" : { "111_0500_00" : 3 } }

db.wnitest.find()
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-07-30T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "new" : 3, "act" : NaN, "channel_new" : { "11
1_0500_00" : 5 }, "ver_new" : { "0\uff0E9\uff0E0" : 2, "1\uff0E0\uff0E0" : 3 }, "channel_ver_new" :
{ "111_0500_00*#*0\uff0E9\uff0E0" : 2, "111_0500_00*#*1\uff0E0\uff0E0" : 3 } } }
>
```

here is my python code:

```
mapper = Code("""function(){
var date = new Date('2015-7-30');
emit(date,this);
}""")
reducer = Code("""function(key, values){
var sum = {"new":0,"act":0,"channel_new":{},"ver_new":{},"channel_ver_new":{}};
values.forEach(function(doc){
sum.new += doc.new;
sum.act += doc.act;
var category = {"channel_new":1,"ver_new":1,"channel_ver_new":1};
for(var item in category)
{
  var t = Object.keys(doc[item]);
  for(var i in t){
   if(Object.keys(sum[item]).indexOf(t[i])!=-1){
    sum[item][t[i]] += doc[item][t[i]];
   }else{
    sum[item][t[i]] = doc[item][t[i]];
   }
  }
}
});
return sum;
}
    """)
db.daily.map_reduce(mapper,reducer,'weekly')

Here is result:

> db.weekly.find()
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-07-29T16:00:00Z"), "value" : { "_id" : ObjectId("55bef4eaf6d9e26e37e3e380"),
 "date" : ISODate("2015-07-06T00:00:00Z"), "new" : 1, "channel_ver_new" : { "111_0500_00*#*0\uff0E9\
uff0E0" : 2 }, "ver_new" : { "0\uff0E9\uff0E0" : 2 }, "channel_new" : { "111_0500_00" : 2 } } }
>
```

This is response for pymongo's map_reduce:

```
{u'timing': {u'total': 59, u'mapTime': 0, u'emitLoop': 57, u'mode': u'mixed', u'reduceTime': 0}, u'counts': {u'input': 1, u'reduce': 0, u'emit': 1, u'output': 1}, u'timeMillis': 59, u'ok': 1.0, u'result': u'weekly'}
```

reduce is 0, why?

Comment: Okay. The code inclusion is better. Your are emitting `emit(date,this)` here, which seems a little redundant since there is likely a "date" field somewhere in the document. What is the document structure of the input? You likely have a variance in your mapper "output" to reducer "output", which is a common mapReduce mistake. Edit again to show a typical document.

Comment: Hi, see the db.daily.find() output, you're right that it has 'date' field, I think has nothing to do with this, still the same when I changed to annother. Seems reduce is not run with pymongo map_reduce.

Comment: Use he "Edit" link on your question. No code or data in comments.

Comment: Will you stop making your own presumptions and please post the details you have been asked to. If every person that actually had a problem was really because of a "bug" in software you are using then the world would be at a halt. 99.9999% of the time, the problem is in your code. That is why I want to see the original document format for input purposes.

Comment: Hi Blakes, already added db.daily.find() :-)

Comment: Is that the "output" from the mapReduce or the "input"? Not clear in your question

Comment: Added response of pymongo map_reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is any fault of the python driver, just that your reduce function is not set up correctly in the first place.

In order to sum the values for all possible keys, then your code should look more like this:

```js
var mapper  = function() {
    delete this.date;
    emit(date,this);
};

var reducer = function(key,values) {
    var reduced = { 
        "new": 0, 
        "channel_new": {}, 
        "ver_new": {}, 
        "channel_ver_new": {} 
    };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        reduced.new += value.new;

        Object.keys(reduced).filter(function(key) {
            return key != "new";
        }).forEach(function(key){
            if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                Object.keys(value[key]).forEach(function(iKey) {
                    if (!reduced[key].hasOwnProperty(ikey))
                        reduced[key][ikey] = 0;
                    reduced[key][ikey] += value[key][ikey];
                })
            }
        });
    });

    return reduced;
};

var options = {
    "out": { "inline": 1 },
    "scope": { "date": new Date("2015-07-27") },
    "query": { 
        "date": { 
            "$gte": new Date("2015-07-27"), "$lt": new Date("2015-08-03")
        }
    }
}

db.daily.mapReduce(mapper,reducer,options);
```

That gives the correct traversal of all elements and aggregates correctly given the query range selection.

Comment: Blake, you're right. I found when map_reduce is running, actually, map input document is only one, so, the reduce is skipped, then, just return whatever map function returned. Your code is pretty good. Thanks.

Comment: @Wesley Well yes. After going though all the trouble to get the information from you then it is clear that the reducer is not structured correctly. So thankyou for acknowleding how helpful I have been here.